# React& Typescript: Error while starting the development server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm-scripts, npm-start, react-scripts

I was trying to create a new typescript-react project by using the command

```
npx create-react-app todo-list --template typescript
```

well the installation went well, but when I run the project with

```
npm start
```

I am having the below error

```
PS C:\Users\ayex\Desktop\freecodecamp\React&Typescript\todo-list> npm start

> todo-list@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'Typescript\todo-list\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ayex\Desktop\freecodecamp\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

From the error message you can clear see that it is trying to look for react-scripts file but in the wrong directory, I do not know how to solve this. I tried to delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file and run `npm install` ended up with no lack.
here is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "todo-list",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.39",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO F***ING WAY!
how could folder naming be the cause of the problem I named the folder `React&Typescript`  and the ampersand was causing all this error, wasting my precious 2 day. when I name it to `React-Typescript` it immediately works.
it all make sense now I guess, in the error message the ampersand was causing it not to read the full directory path it cuts it in the middle of the name `React&Typescript`.

`'Typescript\todo-list\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

it is really astonishing that no one has faced this issue, me being the first person!
note I have used vite this time instead of npx create-react-app and still was facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add type module in your package.json file.

```json
{
  "name": "todo-list",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module"   
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.39",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: no lack, It does not work